# Jquery - get selector when using after

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have code:

```
$('#.element').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).after('<div>...</div>');
});
```

And I want to do some other stuff with created `div` in the same line of code without using its `ID`. How can I do that?

I mean something like this:

```
$(this).after('<div>...</div>').css('border', '1px').fadeOut('5000');
```

This above code will set `border` and `fadeOut` to element `$(this)`, but I want it to be done to new created `div` element.

Comment: Try `$(this).after($('<div />').css('border', '1px').fadeOut('5000'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why `.insertAfter()` have been introduced, It will return the objects in a reverse manner.

```
$('<div>...</div>').css('border', '1px').insertAfter($(this)).fadeOut('5000');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insertAfter`. It does the same thing that `after`, but the returned value is the inserted object. So you can chain calls on it.

```
$('<div/>').insertAfter($(this)).css('border', '1px').fadeOut('5000');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `after()` returns the original element/collection to which `after()` was applied, rather than the created elements that were inserted, simply use `next()`:

```
$(this).after('<div>...</div>').next().css('border', '1px').fadeOut('5000');
```

Or you could use `insertAfter()` and apply the methods as you create the element:

```
$('<div />', {
    'css' : {
        'border' : '1px'
     }).insertAfter(this).fadeOut();
```

Or, alternatively, you could even create an alternative jQuery method – as a plugin – which takes the functionality of `after()` but instead returns the created element(s); such as:

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.afterAlt = function (str) {
        this.after(str);
        return this.next();
    };
})(jQuery);

snippet.log($('.demo').afterAlt('<span>hi</span>').map(function(){
  return this.tagName;
}).get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div class="demo">div 1</div>
<div class="demo">div 2</div>
<div class="demo">div 3</div>
<div class="demo">div 4</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7ugm5cvc/).

Comment: Will not work `after !== append`, so you cannot use `find` here

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).after('<div>...</div>').next().css('border', '1px').fadeOut('5000');
```